# Odd Javascript behavior: Iterative changes to Div ignored unless Alert is present

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, userscripts, tampermonkey

My code includes a function with a lengthy `For` loop. Near the end of the loop is a code line that, with each iteration, increases the width of a `div` that serves as a status bar. The problem?  The status bar's width only increases if there is an `alert` line above it to alert me of the current loop counter.  When I comment out that `alert`, the web page freezes, I hear a lot of computer whirring, and eventually I get a *A web page is slowing down your browser. What would you like to do?* browser message.  The function is outlined below:

```
function processData(dataArr) {
// initialize the status bar
   var bar = document.createElement('div');
   bar.setAttribute("style","top:7px;left:125px;height:25px;width:400px");
   bar.id="StatusBar";
   document.body.appendChild(bar);
// now start the loop:
   for (var i=0;i<dataArr.length;i++) {
       // do a lot of string manipulation and parsing on dataArr[i]
// update the status bar every 50 iterations
       if (Math.ceil(i/50) == Math.floor(i/50)) {
           alert('Loop # '+(i+1)); // If this line is commented out, the status bar stops updating! 
       }
       bar.style.width = Math.round(((1+i)/dataArr.length)*400)+'px';
   }
// loop has finished last iteration, remove status bar
   document.body.removeChild(bar);
}
```

The `alert` line noted above is the line whose presence makes the difference between the code functioning normally (data gets processed, the status bar grows with loop counter) or the web page freezing and getting a *web page is slowing down your browser* warning. Can anyone explain why a seemingly benign `alert` line would so dramatically change the functionality of this code?

The following fact is likely irrelevant, but just in case it isn't:   the above function is called from within an `onload: function()` code block of a `xmlhttpRequest` in a second function.

Updated: I just found [another possibly-related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276360/issue-loading-script-unless-alert-is-present) which suggests maybe the underlying cause is that this function is called from within the `onload` block of an `xmlhttpRequest`. The answers to that question do not provide a solution to my problem, however, and the questions do not deal with quite the same topic (I am using a userscript, and page-loading does not seem to be the problem, as I am able to generate the initial status bar without any difficulty. With the exception of updating the status bar at the end of each loop, no web page manipulation is being conducted within the loop.)

2nd update:  corrected so that the brackets are correctly closed

Comment: Your brackets don't add up. Also it would be very helpful if you can provide a working example for us to try ourselves.

Comment: I just added the missing closing bracket.  The code is really long and complicated, so will take me a while to parse out  (and then test) the relevant code to provide a fully-working example.

Comment: Changes to the DOM aren't rendered until the Javascript returns. This allows you to make lots of changes, and the user just sees the final result, not all the intermediate states. If you want the user to see changes, you need to use timers, CSS transitions, or animation frames.

Comment: @Barmar So does the `alert` command force the DOM to be rendered, sort of like a pseudo timer, and that's why keeping the `alert` in the code allowed the DOM changes to be rendered immediately and not so if the `alert` were commented out?

Comment: Yes, the alert invokes the event loop, to wait for the response, and the DOM is rendered. I think this may be browser-dependent, I've seen questions where they said it worked in one browser but not another.

Comment: @Barmar, just one more question for clarification:  when you say "Changes to the DOM aren't rendered until the Javascript returns", could you specify what you mean by "until the Javascript returns"?  Returns to what? Until it exits the `for` loop?  or until the function returns to the other function (the one using `xmlhttpRequest` call)?  Or did you mean something else?  I'm trying to compose a clear answer but wanting to insure that I completely understand the full story.

Comment: When all the Javascript functions complete and you're back in the browser's main event loop.

Answer (score -1):

When inside a `for` loop, the presence of a seemingly innocuous `alert` allows a `CSS` command to immediately change a `div` (the `div` change command immediately follows the `alert` inside the loop) with each the loop increment ***because*** the `alert` command invokes the event loop to *wait* for a response from the user (e.g., hitting the `OK` button on the alert box). During this wait, the DOM changes can be rendered.  Without the `alert` command (or some alternative way such as timers to explicitly cause real-time DOM change rendering), changes are not rendered on the web page until all Javascript functions are complete and the code's execution has returned to the browser's main event loop. In my case, this point in the code would be when the function returned to the second function that called it, within the `onload:` block of an `xmlhttpRequest`.

An explicit  illustration of this behavior: while the `CSS` command to increase `div` width was supposed to occur at the end of each `for` loop increment, the `div` (serving as a status bar) instead only grew on every 50th loop iteration, the same frequency that the `alert` was coded to execute. To satisfy the need for a status bar to show data processing progress, I restructured the work flow in my code: instead of waiting until all chunks of data from the second function's `xmlhttpRequest` had been downloaded before calling the above function, I called the above function to process each chunk of data as it was downloaded. The status bar that was working well within the `xmlhttpRequest` block now represents the combined download and processing of the data.

Comment: I am asking for clarification as to what the perceived problem is with this answer, motivating the need for a down-vote. Does the answer provide inaccurate information? If so, can you please specify what is inaccurate so that this answer can be improved to help other new users as myself?